# Forwarding from my domain's email account to Gmail - is it possible to compose?

Tags: gmail

I want to forward all my emails to my Gmail so I can have them from one account, but I was curious if it's possible to reply to emails and compose emails from my non-gmail account that is forwarding there.

I tried to Google but could not come up with a definitive answer. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You will be switching which email account the reply/forward/composed email is "From" while typing up the email.  In order to have more than just your gmail account in that list though, you have to add that other account (which you will need the server SMTP details for) into your gmail settings. (Gear at top right -> Settings -> Accounts -> Add another email address you own)

Details here : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. I do that with several email addresses.

There are a couple of steps you need to complete:

You need to have those other email addresses either automatically forward your email to your Gmail address, or have Gmail pull the messages via POP3 (`Settings > Accounts > Check mail from other accounts (using POP3):` [Gmail help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289)).

You will also need to set up Gmail so that you can "send as" those other addresses. That setting is found under `Settings > Accounts > Send mail as:` ([Gmail help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)). When you add an email address, Google will send a message to that email address with a link you need to follow to confirm that you "own" that address.

Once confirmed, you can now send new messages or reply to messages and change the "From:" address being used. One very useful feature is to turn on "When replying to a message: Reply from the same address the message was sent to" so that your reply defaults to the same address where the message was originally set. (You can always change it manually, but it is nice to keep from leaking your Gmail address to, say, your co-workers.)